# Unzipping OSM2VectorTiles after extracing with MBUtil

Tags: pbf, osm2vectortiles

After extracting the tiles from an OSM2VectorTiles set, I have a proper folder structure with `.pbf`-files. However, OpenLayers cannot read those files.

I believe this is because they are zipped. So, whats the proper way to extract those into unzipped usable `.pbf`-files?

Answer (score 6):

The vector tiles can be unpacked from MBTiles (SQLite) container and hosted in a folder structure - the same way as raster tiles are typically made with a software like [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com) or GDAL2Tiles. The demonstration of such approach is visible at http://klokantech.github.io/mapbox-gl-js-offline-example/.

To unpack and ungzip the tiles I have used [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil):

```
./mb-util --image_format=pbf countries.mbtiles countries
gzip -d -r -S .pbf *
find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.pbf \;
```

(this is text from section "Host the vector tiles without any server at all" in the README.md in our repo https://github.com/klokantech/vector-tiles-sample).

In case you want to host on Amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage - you can use MapTiler 7.1+ graphical user interface to efficiently upload the vector tiles directly from MBTiles to the cloud storage - or the command-line "cloudpush" utility which comes with [MapTiler Pro](http://www.maptiler.com/demo/) and is able to push up to 16000 tiles / second.

Hosting of MBTiles with vector tiles dynamically is also extremely easy with our open-source server projects such as:

- [TileServer PHP](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php) a single .php file on any LAMP web hosting
- [TileServer Mapnik](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-mapnik).
- Node.js powered [TileServer GL](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) or it's [light](https://github.com/osm2vectortiles/tileserver-gl-light/) variant

Recently we host the vector tiles usually with TileServer GL, because it is able to create raster tiles on the server side from the vector tiles. See: http://blog.klokantech.com/2016/08/tileserver-gl-maps-with-gl-json-styles.html

Comment: the last line in the command wont work (find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.pbf \;), gives me an error "FIND: parameter format not correct"